# Beginner Python: Where to "while"?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

**tl;dr**: My code "works", in that it gives me the answer I need.  I just can't get it to stop running when it reaches that answer.  I'm stuck with scrolling back through the output.

I'm a complete novice at programming/Python.  In order to hone my skills, I decided to see if I could program my own "solver" for *Implied Equity Risk Premium* from Prof. Damodaran's Valuation class.  Essentially, the code takes some inputs and "guesses and tests" a series of interest rates until it gets a "close" value to the input.

Right now my code spits out an output list, and I can scroll back through it to find the answer.  It's correct.  However, I cannot for the life of me get the code to "stop" at the correct value with the **while** function.

I have the following code:

```
per = int(input("Enter the # of periods forecast ->"))
divbb = float(input("Enter the initial dividend + buyback value ->"))
divgr = float(input("Enter the div + buyback growth rate ->"))
tbondr = float(input("Enter the T-Bond rate ->"))+0.000001
sp = int(input("Enter the S&P value->"))

total=0
pv=0


for i in range(1,10000):
    erp = float(i/10000)
    a = divbb
    b = divgr
    pv = 0
    temppv = 0
    print (sp-total, erp)
    for i in range(0, per):
        a=a * (1+b)
        temppv = a / pow((1+erp),i)
        pv=pv+temppv
    lastterm=(a*1+tbondr)/((erp-tbondr)*pow(1+erp,per))
    total=(pv+lastterm)
```

From his example, with the inputs:

- per = 5
- divbb = 69.46
- divgr = 0.0527
- tbondr = 0.0176
- sp = 1430

By scrolling back through the output, I can see my code produces the correct minimum at epr=0.0755.

My question is: where do I stick the **while** to stop this code at that minimum?  I've tried a lot of variations, but can't get it.  What I'm looking for is, basically:

while (sp-total) > |1|, keep running the code.

Comment: You don't need a `while` - that's a type of loop. You need an `if` to break out of your current loop. Maybe `if sp - total < 1: break` after the `print`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
per = 5
divbb = 69.46
divgr = 0.0527
tbondr = 0.0176
sp = 1430

total=0
pv=0

i = 1
while(abs(sp-total)) > 1:
    erp = i/10000.
    a = divbb
    b = divgr
    pv = 0
    temppv = 0
    print (sp-total, erp)
    for j in range(0, per):
        a=a * (1+b)
        temppv = a / pow((1+erp),j)
        pv=pv+temppv
    lastterm=(a*1+tbondr)/((erp-tbondr)*pow(1+erp,per))
    total=(pv+lastterm)
    i += 1
```

should work. Obviously, there are a million ways to do this. But the general gist here is that the while loop will stop as soon as it meets the condition. You could also test every time in the for loop and include a break statement, but because you don't know when it will stop, I think a while loop is better in this case.

Let me give you a quick rundown of two different ways you could solve a problem like this:

Using a while loop:

```
iterator = start value
while condition(iterator):
    do some stuff
    increment iterator
```

Using a for loop:

```
for i in xrange(startvalue, maxvalue):
    do some stuff
    if condition:
        break
```

Two more thing: if you're doing large ranges, use the generator xrange. Also, it's probably a bad idea to reuse `i` inside your `for` loop.

I recommend CS101 from [Udacity.com](http://udacity.com) for learning Python. Also, if you're interested in algorithms, work through the problems at [projecteuler.com](http://projecteuler.com)

Comment: That worked 99.9% of the way (stops at 0.754 rather than 0.755.  I think I can solve that)!  I'm not sure what I was missing, seemed to have tried everything.  I appreciate the quick response and the tips!

Comment: @JarbyMcGroo Oh, whoops. It's not printing the last one because the while loop doesn't run again! Since the test succeeds, it doesn't print. Below the while loop you can print the variable, it should be correct.

Comment: @ragaos Thanks again!  I'm actually just starting to work through Udacity course.  I decided to take a break to see if I could apply the basics to solve a "real" problem.  Not quite yet!

Comment: projecteuler.com is insanely great. Try out the first few problems! I think you'll be pleased.